# Failing to serve static assets via Cloudfront/EGDE addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to get all my static assets to be served via the [EDGE](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/edge) add-on available on Heroku. I've added the following lines to my **production.rb** file

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max age=2592000"
config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["https://1a2b3c4d.cloudfront.net"]
```

But it seems that is not enough. When I inspect my assets they are stilled served via the assets folder. On Herokus guide on EDGE it states that adding `config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["https://1a2b3c4d.cloudfront.net"]`
 should do it.

I suspect there is something else I need to add or that there is something else in my **production.rb** that prevents the assets to be served via EDGE but I don't know what that cloud be.

My **production.rb** as a whole

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
config.assets.compile = false
config.active_storage.service = :local
config.force_ssl = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.log_tags = [:request_id]
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max age=2592000"
config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["https://1a2b3c4d.cloudfront.net"]
```

Running on rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.1

Edit #1 - I restated the Heroku application when I deployed the new code.

Comment: Botten, since you're in the config file, you should always list if you restarted the heroku app since making the changes.  It's a small thing but helpful to people trying to trouble shoot with you.

Comment: @Mirv-Matt Thanks for the heads up! I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I noticed that you're editing `production.rb` ... this server you're working on isn't live & helping clients right?

If it isn't, I'd say your next step is to change the parts of the configuration which prevent your setting from working.

This means you're going to have to read the configuration documentation at from rails guides eventually, but first ...

Why do you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` ... when we do assets with ngix this is off as rails isn't serving the assets.  Also in modern rails apps they use `config.public_file_server.enabled` which in your case needs to be 'false'.

---

Since we didn't watch you setup the app - we can't immediately point out where the mistake ... so you're in for a couple hours of trouble shooting ...

- If your quick diagnostics fail, fork the app (from before you first attempted the change in question) and/or use staging environment
- check list completing each step from fresh start of the process
- get a working skeleton demo from someone else & do the checklist again
- at that point it's not the integration it's something in your own code or data ... perhaps stick your stuff into the skeleton demo